# CS Circles - Python - Lists - It's Natural exercise

Tags: python, python-3.x, computer-science

Here is a problem that I am having trouble solving:

Write a function `naturalNumbers` which takes a positive integer `n` as input, and returns a list `[1, 2, ...]` consisting of the first n natural numbers.

Here is the code that I have so far:

```
def naturalNumbers(x):
   x = input()
   myList = []
   for i in range (0, x):
      return myList = myList + [i]
      print(myList)
```

I'm really confused as to when to put `return` for functions.

Comment: return is always the LAST thing you do. after the return the function exits and no more code in that function will run

Comment: Why are you passing `x` as a function param, and override that value taking the returned value from `input()` ?

Comment: While the answers below are fine OP, you can use a simple list comprehension to accomplish your task: `[n for n in range(1, x + 1)]`. It would look much cleaner than doing a "regular" for loop.

Answer (score 1):

you are working very hard
the function `range()` returns a an object castable to list, so all you need to do is

```
def naturalNumbers(x):
    return list(range(1,x + 1)) #didnt notice we are in python 3
```

0 is not considered a natural number

Comment: @leaf on python 2 im doing `type(range(1,5))` and getting list, are range objects a python 3 thing?

Comment: No problem. Glad to help.

Answer (score 0):

```
def naturalNumbers(n):
    n = input()
    myList = []
    for i in range(1, n + 1):
        myList.append(i)
    return myList
```

Or use *list comprehension*:

```
def naturalNumbers(n):
    n = input()
    myList = [i for i in range(1, n + 1)]
    return myList
```

`return` is the end of a function, it should be outside of a loop.

Comment: In Python the `range()` function is _exclusive_. Which means that is will go up to `n` numbers, but stop there. You need to do `range(0, n + 1)` instead.

Answer (score 0):

Your are mixing both your 'main' code and the function that you are being asked to write.

let your function be only for your list generating function `naturalNumbers`.
and use a different main function.

you can ignore the main method and the if `__name__ = '__main__'`
this is just to run correctly with good form.

```
# this method outputs a list from 0 to x
def naturalNumbers (x):
    l = list[]
    for i in range(0, x+1):
        list.append(i)
    return l

def main():
    x = input()
    # should check if x is an integer (defensive programming)
    print (naturalNumbers(x))

if __name__ = "__main__"
    main()
```

- also depending on the definition used natural numbers can start form 0 or 1

Answer (score 0):

Return is the output from a function. Without the return the function doesn't 'give back' anything to where it was called.

```
def naturalNumbers(n):
  return [x for x in range(0,n)]

print(naturalNumbers(5))
```

The above print statement uses the output of natural numbers and will print [0,1,2,3,4].

Say we remove the return and just assign it to a value.

```
def naturalNumbers(n):
  numbers = [x for x in range(0,n)]
  #assignment rather than return, we could do other operations.

print(naturalNumbers(5))
#returns None
```

The above print statement prints 'None' as this is the default return value in Python

Comment: In Python the `range()` function is exclusive. Which means that is will go up to `n` numbers, but stop there. You need to do `range(0, n + 1)` instead.

Answer (score 0):

Try this simple method:

```
def naturalNumbers(n):
   myList = []
   for i in range(0,n):
      myList = myList+[i+1]
   return myList
```